# Is ther any way to split the uploaded file name extension and display it in diffrent html element?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I uploaded files from the index.html page and extensions are .jpg, .pdf, Docx, and mp4 into my project and able to display only jpg files and used scr for that and I need to use if else condition according to extension and display in HTML elements. so that I need to split the file name and get that extension and accordingly used if-else condition. I am not able to split files for the index.html page using split(). please help and all code included below

**index.html**

```
{% for i in phone %}

<!-- <img src="{{i.document.url}}" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="200" height="200; display: flex;"> -->
<h1>{{i.document.url}}</h1>

<h2>{{i.document.path}}</h2>



{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
def Home(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        if len(request.FILES) == 0:
            return redirect("/drive")
        else:
            photo = request.FILES['doc'] 
            Upload.objects.create(document = photo) 
            return redirect("/drive")
   
    

    if request.method == "GET": 
        photo = Upload.objects.all() 
        context = {
             'phone': photo 
             }   

    return render(request, 'Home.drive.html', context)
```

**modles.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Upload(models.Model):
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
```

- Note: Waiting for positive response and please i am beginner so that i need full code instead of hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom [TemplateTag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) like [this](https://newbedev.com/django-filefield-how-to-return-filename-only-in-template).

I have one piece of advice for you:
I think it's better to use the function for upload_to attribute.

```py
def get_image_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('Products', 'images', instance.name, filename)

class YourModel(models.model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_upload_path)
```

Comment: still don't get it, could you please write a complete working code because I am a beginner.

Comment: No, The world is cruel than what you thought. :)        Search into the net with subjects that I mentioned. You can find your answer on your own.